# Flatfile cacheing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to finish up a long term project and looking over my code looking for inneficienies and attempting to tidy them up.

The data structure in mySQL is an undirected graph, on the whole I'm quite happy with the performance though I am sticking to old habits such as cacheing the results in flat files where data does not change readily despite being dynamic. I'm also using flatfiles as my site configuration database, this is approximately 40 lines with a structure `ConfVar=ConfVarValue`.

Is this an efficient hybrid use of flatfiles and SQL? I've constantly questioned myself whilst designing this structure whether the flatfiles are secure enough (they are all stored sub doc root)? And are they providing me with the efficiency I was ultimately aiming for in a scalable manner?

Any guidance, thoughts, observations anyone has had whilst designing similar data models would be invaluable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use memcache to the cache the result?

Comment: Just googled memcache, I can certainly see the benefits storing the site config into memory for the scripts use, however I define all the config flatfile vars as constants, and have modeled my entire access layer using these constants. Thanks for the heads up though, I will take a closer look at memcache for the future!

Comment: I mean cache the sql result with memcache.

Comment: Apologies, the blinkers were on and the wider scope wasn't seen. Yes, this could work. I'm going to test it and see if it's feasible. I'm a little dubious as memcahce states it stores only a small amount of data and some of the queries I'm sending to SQL return up to 10 nodes. As such the data returned can be in excess of +50 strings (length >29 && <201) / array. These queries typically return the data I am currently flatfile cacheing along with the HTML template I have inserted the data into, leaving me with a flat, static HTML file with a preset expiry time. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It looks you don't have a cacheing problem although memcache uses the ram but you can try to use a ramdisk for your flat files or you can compress it with a fast compression or you can tune the disk (if that is possible).